# How do I compute the minimum or maximum LINE of a bivariate quadratic function?

Tags: optimization, quadratics, quadratic-programming, multivariate-polynomial

Given a bivariate quadratic function:
$$
y = g(x, w) = a x^2 + b x w + c w^2 + d x + e w + f
$$
I think I know that if $b^2 - 4 a c < 0$, then it has a single point minimum (if $a > 0$) or maximum (if $a < 0$) at:
$$
x = \frac{2 c d - b e}{b^2 - 4 a c} ,   w = \frac{2 a e - b d}{b^2 - 4 a c}
$$
Please correct me if that is incorrect.

But if $b^2 - 4 a c = 0$ and $2 c d - b e = 0$ and/or(?) $2 a e - b d = 0$, then it has a minimum (if $a > 0$) or maximum (if $a < 0$) **line** rather than a single point.  What I do *not* know how to do is to compute that **line** in terms of $a, b, c, d, e,$ and $f$, similar to how I can compute the single point above.  Can anyone tell me how to compute that line?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y = \begin{bmatrix} x & w\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} a & \frac{b}2 \\ \frac{b}2 & c\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x \\ w\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}d & e \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x \\ w\end{bmatrix} + f$$

$$\begin{bmatrix} 2a & b \\ b & 2c\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x \\ w\end{bmatrix} = -\begin{bmatrix} d \\ e\end{bmatrix}$$

If $b^2-4ac=0,$  $a>0$, then it is positive semidefinite. If $2ae-bd=0$, then the system is consistent.  The line is

$$2ax + bw = -d$$

Similarly if $b^2-4ac=0,$  $a<0$, it is negative semidefinite and we get the same line.

Comment: So, given the symmetry, is there a case where you'd get the line $2cw + bx = -e$? Perhaps when $2cd - be=0$?

Comment: they are the same line. The system is singular but consistent, and the matrix is non-zero, the solution is a line.

Comment: actually, if $b=c=0$, then the $2cw+bx=-e$ become $0=0$. but since we assume $a>0$, $2ax+bw=-d$ is a line. If you assume $c>0$, then $2cw+bx=-e$ is a line. If both $a>0$ and $c>0$, then we have both line being the same.